# Delete multiple records from a table using subsonic T4 templates?

Tags: templates, subsonic, records, delete-record

Using templates, how can I delete multiple records from a table in same Delete statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question's a bit ambiguous but based on another question you've posted I think you're trying to delete based on a list of Ids or something similar. You can do that using a fluent query as follows:

```
List<int> peopleIds = new List<int> { 121, 122, 35, 4 };

new SubSonic.Query.Delete<Person>(new MyDB().Provider)
    .Where(PersonTable.IdColumn).In(peopleIds)
    .Execute();
```

Comment: Right on the target. Just to add for others, Execute(), in this case, returns int which is number of records processed. 
Thank you Adam :)