# subsonic ActiveRecord: Lambda Parameter not in scope

Tags: activerecord, lambda, subsonic

I am trying to delete a list of albums from an Album table. Below is the syntax I am using, but it fails saying `Lambda Parameter not in scope`:

`Album.Delete(x => (ListOfIds).Contains(x.Id));`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Contains method isn't currently supported in SubSonic's linq implementation. I've posted an alternative method of doing this in response to your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792473/delete-multiple-records-from-a-table-using-subsonic-t4-templates)